# FacebookLogin loginWithReadPermissions does not request any new permissions

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, aws-sdk, facebook-permissions

Ive previously requested public_profile, user_friends, and email which Facebook will let you use pretty freely in my Swift iOS app but now I'm trying to update the app to request new permissions with loginWithReadPermissions but when it transfers to the login page it just says that I've already granted my app permission and doesn't request the new permissions. Querying the results shows no granted or denied permissions and looking at the Graph Explorer API on the Facebook Developer site shows the same. So I'm looking for suggestions on why my app might not be sending the updated request to the server.

I should note that I'm utilizing the AWS iOS Mobile SDK. I found another answer that overwrites the default Facebook sign in provider to add new permissions to the request but this has the same result.

Also in my output Im seeing the following string which contains all the permissions Im trying to request which makes me think that the request is going out but something else is happening

```
scope=email%2Cuser_birthday%2Cuser_hometown%2Cuser_friends%2Cpublic_profile%2Cuser_about_me
```

Comment: You’re testing this with a user that has a role in the app, yes? (Otherwise you won’t be able to ask the user for permissions that have not been reviewed by Facebook yet.) Try removing the app from your settings completely https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications, and then give it another go. Any changes?

Comment: You're totally right. I had to move my app to a new Facebook app id and I never registered as a dev on the new page. Thanks.